# Oracle date format -- data reader not recognizing to_char function

Tags: c#, oracle

Basically just pulling a date out in YYYYMMDD and I can do this fine in a query analyzer but when I try to run this query in C# I keep getting a column not found error it also seems to have a hard time doing concatenation (but that isn't so much of a problem) so a little unsure of what is happening here..I really just want my to_char function to work. Ideas? Thanks!

```
  string oradb = "user id=x;password=x;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)"
        +"(HOST=x)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=x)));";

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
    cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT to_char(ProblemDate, 'yyyymmdd'), data1, data2,"
        +"data4, data5, data6"
        +" WHERE ( ProblemDate >='03-oct-2011' ) "
        +"AND ( ProblemDate <= '08-oct-2011' ) AND " 
        +"( data1 in ( '3','5','6' ) )";
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string fileOut1 = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
    string fileOut = fileOut1 + "Text5.txt";
    // Creates the file
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileOut);
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string data1= (string)dr["data1"].ToString();
            string data2 = (string)dr["data3"].ToString();
            string data3 = (string)dr["data4"];
            string data4 = (string)dr["data5"].ToString();
            string data5 = (string)dr["data6"].ToString();
            string ProblemDate = (string)dr["ProblemDate"].ToString();

            //remove the comma
            char[] MyChar = { ',' };

            sw.WriteLine(data1.PadRight(10) + data2.PadRight(5) + data3.TrimEnd(MyChar) + "000" +
                data4 + "000" + data5+  ProblemDate + "  " + "N" );

            Label1.Text = "File created successfully.<br />";
            Label1.Text += fileOut1;
        }
        // Closes the connenction.
        sw.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "No data written.";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try aliasing the column? eg.

```
SELECT to_char(ProblemDate, 'yyyymmdd') as ProblemDate, data1, data2 ...
```

As a side note, you might run into issues with your date comparisons in your `WHERE` clause. Granted I don't know anything about your application, client and/or server regional settings and maybe your example was just for illustration purposes, but I'm thinking it would be safer to use `TO_DATE` than string comparisons:

```
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT to_char(ProblemDate, 'yyyymmdd') as ProblemDate, data1, data2,"
    +"data4, data5, data6"
    +" WHERE ( ProblemDate >= TO_DATE('03-oct-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY') ) "
    +"AND ( ProblemDate <= TO_DATE('08-oct-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY') ) AND " 
    +"( data1 in ( '3','5','6' ) )";
```

Comment: I didn't notice this at first, but as @Rajesh pointed out in his answer, there is no `FROM` clause which will also be an issue. :)

Comment: @mtnwk Did this answer (or another one) solve your problem? If so please mark the appropriate answer as accepted.

Comment: from clause was omitted from question by mistake

Comment: @mtnwk No worries, you can always edit your questions after the fact to fix or improve them!

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, can you print the query from inside Java and see the actual query being fired?

These are the issues I saw ...

```
SELECT to_char(ProblemDate, 'yyyymmdd'), data1, data2,
       data4, data5, data6
       WHERE ( ProblemDate >='03-oct-2011' )
         AND ( ProblemDate <= '08-oct-2011' ) 
         AND data1 in ( '3','5','6' ) );
```

1. There is **no from clause** and table_name in the query.
2. Priobably not the cause of the issue, but wanted to point it out.
   Since you are doing a to_char, I am assuming ProblemDate is a date datatype. It is always recommended to use explicit cast when comparing, so change the conditions to

   **ProblemDate >=to_date('03-oct-2011','dd-mon-yyyy') and 
   ProblemDate <=to_date('08-oct-2011',,'dd-mon-yyyy')**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably related to this line:

```
string draw_date = (string)dr["ProblemDate"].ToString();
```

Try labeling the function as something, because you aren't calling "ProblemDate" you are calling a function. If you output the array that comes back, you could probably see what it's called.

EDIT: also you might want to check this line

```
string data2 = (string)dr["data3"].ToString();
```

as there is a data2, but not a data3 in the call to the DB